# Add new layout to an existing item in RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-viewholder

I would like to add a new container `layout` to an existing XML item of a `RecyclerView`

Here is an example of what I would like to do (based on `R.layout.item_simple` XML)

```
@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
    return new ViewHolder(inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_simple, parent, false));
}
```

`R.layout.item_simple` content at `RecyclerView.Adapter` creation:

```
  ______ LINEAR LAYOUT
     ______ IMAGE VIEW
     ______ TEXT VIEW
```

What I want to do by adding a new `layout` to the user view:

```
  ______ RELATIVE LAYOUT
      ______ LINEAR LAYOUT
         ______ IMAGE VIEW
         ______ TEXT VIEW
```

Is it possible to change this item view, preferably into the `RecyclerView.Adapter` ?

Comment: then add userview layout into that set visiablity as gone when you need then set visiable.

Comment: @AndroidTeam That's a way to do it indeed, but in my case I would like this mainLayout to be added only in Java, not in XML

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to achieve this. First is to add always the additional layout to your `item_simple` and hide/show. The second approach is to use `getItemViewType` to return different `layout` types. This way `onCreateViewHolder` gets called once for each type, and you can inflate different `layout`s

Comment: How can I use `getItemViewType` to return different `layout` types exactly?

Comment: to answer your question, I need to know how you decide if you are gonna show or not the additional piece of layout

Answer (score 0):

You just simply inflate your layout here like `item_simple`and use show/hide view by using condition. like

```
mainlayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

and

```
mainlayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

Comment: That's a way to do it indeed, but in my case I would like this mainLayout to be added only in Java, not in XML

Comment: you should also do same thing as a programmatically.
 View v = findViewById(R.id.pnlLatLng);
v.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

Comment: I mean. I would like this `mainLayout` to be created in Java only. In `RecyclerView.Adapter` for example. This is the purpose of my post, I don't know how to add a new `layout` to an existing XML item.